# Why Decision trees performs better than logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-trees, logistic-regression

I'm working on a machine learning project, a classification of (100 x 100) Images (every pixel contains 0 or 255), my training set contains 10000 examples (which I split into 2 parts 80% training/20% for testing). When I applied Logistic regression algorithm I had 22 % of accuracy and when I applied a decision trees algorithm I had 55 % of accuracy, but I can't understand why the second algorithm gives a better result.

Comment: Why would you apply ML Algos on DL stuffs? I can't get that intuition. Can you explain, Why you did that?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a neural network for this? The challenge with the two approaches you're using is that both models are not great at handling a large number of features and you, essentially, have 10,000 features. So, my guess is that even with the decision tree,  you're probably just picking up some background pixels that are inflating your accuracy rate. There's probably something there that the decision tree is picking up and then "locking" you into that branch of the model, which is less than ideal. Using a neural network can help you create a model that can do more nuanced choices

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a decision tree grows itteratively putting more significance on the number of observed units within a node,  whilst a logistic regression attempts to fit all observations in some line of theoretical distribution. The former approach, apparently, can bring more information from smaller counts than the latter.
As a result, a tree combines the probabilities of classification from each node achieved by a "heterogeneous" ruleset, while a regression cares more about a "homogeneous" formula which describes rather the magnitude of a factor significance to fitting that distribution. Having that said, a log reg is not really a classifier, but is often used as one.
For a better understanding of the two approaches, I'd recommend reading where they come from and for what purposes they were developed.